# Chromium deps install problem on libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, libraries, chrome

everyone

I'm trying to build chromium on Ubuntu 14.04.3 in my Virtualbox and get stuck at installing deps running install-build-deps.sh. The problem lies in package **libgl1-mesa-glx:i386**. Here's the main output after running the sh file:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
                        Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

You will have to install the above packages yourself.
```

It seems that this problem blocks other package installation too. Any idea on solving this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing line 181 in instell-build-deps.sh 
From -

181:    `for variant in "-lts-trusty" "-lts-utopic"; do`

To -

181:    `for variant in "-lts-trusty" "-lts-utopic" "-lts-vivid"; do`

Probably happened due to running updates on 14.04.3 which changes the mesa variant.

I've opened an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?q=install-build-deps&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=545708&thanks=545708&ts=1445381132).

Ron

Comment: Problem solved! Really THX!